# Hacer aparecer y desaparecer un div por su posicion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy haciendo una pagina que tiene un banner, ese banner al hacerlo responsive pasa al final de la pagina.
He creado un boton que es fijo en el final de la pantalla para que aparezca cuando el banner este al final de la pagina, este boton te lleva al banner.

Lo que quiero hacer es que si ambos elementos coinciden en el mismo espacio el boton desaparezca, dejando solo el banner..

hay alguna manera de ocultar un elemento si ocupa el mismo espacio que otro o algo asi?

Estoy utilizando react

gracias!

Comment: muestra lo que has intentado hacer, para poderte ayudar

Comment: Te recomiendo que le de [edit] a tu pregunta y como indica @JacksonQuintero agregues lo que has intentado, asi como los resultados esperado y un [repro], lee [ask] para que tengas nociones de como darle el formato adecuado a tu pregunta y que asi sea bien acogida por la comunidad. Corre el riesgo de que sea [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)